# Google Closure Builder - prevent base.js insertion

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

When I build my js project with the Google Closure Builder (SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS), closure include the base.js file in the compiled js file. I dont use the closure-lib. Only goog.provide and goog.require. Is there any way to prevent this insertion?

Answer (score 2):

`goog.provide` and `goog.require` calls are part of Closure-library. The definitions are provided in `base.js`. While I realize that the compiler removes the `goog.require` calls as part of the compilation, `goog.provide` has an actual implementation (your code wouldn't work without it).

If you were to use `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`, then dead code elimination would remove all of the unused sections of `base.js`. However, not all code lends itself to compilation with `ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS`.

You could create your own copy of base.js and only include the necessary definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Kjscompiler has annotation to ignore files and consider them as external: https://github.com/knyga/kjscompiler